# DDR4 column width v/s burst size

Tags: memory

I'm trying to understand how data is going to fill up a 64bit cacheline with x4 DDR4 DIMM.
x4 DDR4 has 16 Banks, 4 Banks each in 4 Bank Groups and each bank is having 4 memory arrays. Burst size is 8.my understanding is column width is the no. of memory arrays within the Bank.
Now my question is when i requested any data how is it fetched i mean whether all the 4 memory arrays provide 8 bits of data to fill the cacheline? how x4 relate with burst size 8?

Answer (score 1):

The **column width** is the size of the Data Bus on the DRAM chip. 
Ex. reading from row 1, column 1 returns 'column width' bits. On DDR4 column width is 64 bits and the row size is 64 Kbits meaning that the row buffer contains 64 Kbits.

A cache line is typically 64 Bytes and **not** 64 bits. A burst size of 8 means that 8 data words are transmitted.

8 data words x 64 bits = 64 Bytes

that is the cache line size.